# Label with button addTarget event not fire

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I have a label in the tableview cell . label have text end of the text has a button that button represent  for user like . everything is fine but problem is `hitForLike` not fire .button click event not fire. do i miss anything

```
var titleLabel : UILabel = {
        var label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 21)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()    

func hitForLike(_ sender : UIButton){

        print("i miss you ....")

    }

func titleWithLikeButton(title:String,isFavorite : Bool){

          titleLabel.text = title

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: titleLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))

        //setup your button here
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: UIControlState.normal)
        let image = UIImage(named: "heart-empty.png")
        button.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hitForLike(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        //Add the button to the text label
        titleLabel.addSubview(button)

}
```

Comment: set label.userinteractionenabled == true and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to enable user interaction on your label, like so:

```
titleLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

So your entire function ends up looking like this:

```
func titleWithLikeButton(title:String,isFavorite : Bool){
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true //enable userinteraction

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: titleLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))

    //setup your button here
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: UIControlState.normal)
    let image = UIImage(named: "heart-empty.png")
    button.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hitForLike(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    //Add the button to the text label
    titleLabel.addSubview(button)
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your cell button target in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, like below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableViewForPAC.dequeueReusableCell( withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.yourButton.tag = indexpath.row
        cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hitForLike(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
       return cell

 }

func hitForLike(_ sender : UIButton){

        print(sender.tag)
        print("i miss you ....")

    }
```